# How can I access the io object with in the io.sockets.on callback?

Tags: javascript, sockets, express

I do not want to change my **sockets** method.  I was hoping to have access to **io** from the **connected** function.

Is this possible?

```
function sockets (server) {
  const io = require('socket.io')(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', connected);
}

const connected = (socket) => {
  socket.on('emit_to_all', data => {
    emitToAll(socket, data);

    // above could be achieved with
    // io.emit('emit_to_all', data);
  });
};
```

I checked on the github [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) but all the preliminary examples did not used a named callback.

I found the essential docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/).

Finally, in the essential docs the API [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/).

Comment: Is this Java? Are you sure? It sure doesn't look like Java to me as we don't have functions or consts. Do you mean JavaScript perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use can do something like this

```
function sockets (server) {
  const io = require('socket.io')(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', connected(io));
}

const connected = (io) => (socket) => {
  socket.on('emit_to_all', data => {
     emitToAll(socket, data);

     // above could be achieved with
     io.emit('emit_to_all', data);
  });
};
```

Comment: In other words, you can use [javascript closure](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36)

Comment: So in simple terms in closure,  inner function has access to outer function's scope. in `connected` function, we are returning a function from a function so  `(socket) => {}` has access to the `io` variable .

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to pass the object in as a parameter, or bind it to the context. If you find the closure syntax confusing, you can also just use bind.

If you do this:

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', connected.bind(io));
```

Then your connected function's `this` will be the to object. Alternatively, you could pass it in as a parameter in a similar way if you update your parameters.

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', connected.bind(null, io));

    const connected = (io, socket) => {
      // Etc
```